# Stop bluetooth answered or outgoing call from automatically unlocking screen

Tags: bluetooth, lock-screens

When I get in the car I leave the phone in my pocket.  Then when the phone rings, I answer the call through the car's controls, but the problem is that this unlocks the screen.  This causes buttons on the screen get activated accidentally and does things like muting the phone, or turning off bluetooth, etc.

Does anybody know a way to stop the phone from unlocking the screen automatically b/c of bluetooth?

Nexus S 2.3.6 on 2012 Volkswagen bluetooth

Comment: Same problem, HTC One X + Volvo bluetooth. iPhone used to return to the lock screen after the call, Androids seem to assume a pickup is an unlock - which isn't what I'd want really. Yet to find a solution.

Comment: Found this while looking for the same thing. No answer, but note that it's [issue ID 17216](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17216) on google's project page for android, so it's a longstanding bug.

Comment: same problem with sony xperia z1 compact - citroen bluetooth